# OwnCloud - storing data on RAID array

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mdadm, owncloud

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 14.10 LTS 64bit. It has an O/S drive, and then a data RAID-1 array mounted under /srv/storage

I've installed OwnCloud server using the default sqlite DB. I've then tried to move the data directory by symlinking /var/www/owncloud/data to /srv/storage   (as well as updating the OwnCloud config file).

When I try to access OwnCloud, I get the message:

*SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file*

I've chowned the /srv/storage directory to www-data:www-data, but that hasn't helped. I have a feeling it's because /srv/storage is mounted with different permissions somehow.

Any tips for how to achieve this? I'd like to have /srv/storage available on OwnCloud, but I also run Plex and Samba, both pointing to this folder...

Comment: Have you verified you can `cd /var/www/owncloud/data` and see what's in `/srv/storage`?  Something I do all the time is use the arguments to `ln` in the wrong order, creating a dangling symlink, but no error message.

Comment: Yes, I can cd around to the correct directory. I know what you mean about the symlink - done that plenty of times!